# Error en el datalayer

Tags: javascript, html5, css3, firebase, google-analytics

Buenas noches comunidad, estoy siguiendo un vídeo, y  cantidad de veces que se reproduce.  Con sus **eventos** con **tag manager**, para obtener su previa visualización de métricas en google analytics,

tengo creado los siguientes eventos en el datalayer, para que así se puedan enlazar (enviar/llamar) con las etiquetas creadas en tag manager

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en que estoy fallando??

muchas gracias por su tiempo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque existe la solución ya creada en Google Tag Manager, puedes:

1. Crear script personalizados entre jQuery y JS para que puedas complementar el anterior script indicado, con custom dimension, custom metrics y enviar más informaciones con una sola etiqueta.
2. Implementar lo mismo en tu sitio web, crearía exactamente el mismo efecto, solo con más líneas de código *(por las variables que tendrás que crear tú y llamarlas posteriormente)*.
3. Con las soluciones de GTM ahorra tiempo en código y más control, en teoría, porque muchas veces necesitas realizar más tareas de recoger variables con otras funciones locales.

Answer (score 0):

estimado para que se muestren tus eventos en Google Analytics, no solo debes crear los datalayers, sino que en paralelo en la cuenta de Google Tag Manager debes crear los eventos con los detalles de los datalayers a capturar y enviar a GA (incluyendo los disparadores y variables a ejecutar para el envío de los eventos).